# Subset a data based on column values with column values from another data and merge in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, dataframe, join

I have two data and I want to subset data1 based on another data2's column value and merge, my data1 looks like:

```
ID   address   phone
123 ....      .....
456 ....      .....
789 ....      .....
101 ....      .....
```

and data2 looks like:

```
ID   City     Zipcode   if_travel
123  ....     ....        ....
456  ....     ....        ....
```

I hope to get data like:

```
ID   address   phone   City     Zipcode   if_travel
123  ....      .....   ....     ....        ....
456  ....      .....   ....     ....        ....
789  ....      .....    NA       NA          NA
101  ....      .....    NA       NA          NA
```

The process seems to alike left-join in python, yet is there any way to do the same process in bash command? Thanks!

Comment: `join --help` will get you started, or search here for `[bash] join file`, there are already 100s of QA on this topic. The only limitation is that the input files have to be sorted by the key column you will use for the joining. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this; here's one:

```
join -o '0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4' -a1 -e 'NA' <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) | awk '{printf "%-7s %-7s %-7s %-7s %-7s %7s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' | sort -nk1
```

input :

file 1:

```
ID   address phone
123 jordan   123
456 usa      144
789 bla      606
101 bla      1616
```

file 2 :

```
ID   City Zipcode if_travel
123  amman 2222   yes
456  zarqa 3030   no
```

output :

```
ID      address phone   City    Zipcode if_travel
101     bla     1616    NA      NA           NA
123     jordan  123     amman   2222        yes
456     usa     144     zarqa   3030         no
789     bla     606     NA      NA           NA
```